# How to design a daemon service which needs to send data over network?

Tags: linux, networking, service

I need to design a service which will provide informations about the host it is running on (such as free disk space, memory, processes, etc...). This data will be sent over the network to a central repository. The service will run as a Linux daemon.

And here comes my question: should I design the service as a server process to which the "central repository" connects and asks for the current data or as a client process which connects to the central repository and delivers its current data. Pros and cons are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You should use snmp to obtain the data from the hosts as it already does what youre talking about.  You can then set up a process to run every N minutes on the central repo server to save the current data.

Comment: Snmp is not really a solution for us, this service will preform other tasks too (for example file operations, updates of our post-unrelated software ...), so we still will need our special process on the remote host... The information gathering is basically used for continuous license validation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters much except if one of the computers is under heavy load and you don't want this communication to get in the way. If that is the case then I would put it up as a server on the light load machine which queries a daemon on the heavy load machine (assuming the heavy load machine is the one you want information from).